# How to understand small and big O notations in probability context?

Tags: probability, notation

I am wondering how I can understand calculation and deductions of  $O_p$ and $o_p$ notations (in probability). For example How can I deduce this:
$$ E[X^2] = E^2[X] + o_p(\sqrt{var(X)}) $$
from this:
$$ E[X^2] = E^2[X] +var(X)$$

I need any source (Hanbook, website, etc.) with examples on this subject. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a reference? As it stands, I am not sure it makes sense, as $var(X)$ is not random, so the qualifier in probability is not really needed.

Comment: @ChristophHanck See [This](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/279070596_A_note_on_high-dimensional_two-sample_test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of this is from my other answer [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/108615/68251).

Pulled from: [http://www2.math.uu.se/~svante/papers/sjN6.pdf](http://www2.math.uu.se/%7Esvante/papers/sjN6.pdf) (definition D5).

> A probabilistic version of $\mathcal{O}$ that is frequently used is the following:
>
> $X_n = O_\text{P}(\alpha_n)$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists constants $C_{\epsilon}$ and $n_{\epsilon}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| \leq C_{\epsilon}\alpha_n) > 1 − \epsilon$ for every $n \geq n_{\epsilon}$. In other words, $X_n/\alpha_n$ is bounded, up to an exceptional event of arbitrarily small (but fixed) positive probability. This is also known as $X_n/\alpha_n$ being bounded in probability.

The precise definition for little-o is also given in this link.